# How to generate rest client api for Spring Boot microservice from source?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, code-generation

Is there a way to configure Spring Boot application to produce (for example, through a gradle task) a jar-file with rest client for it?

I heard of Swagger and libraries like springdoc, springfox, but that generates web api upon application startup. And I want to automate the process of communication between microservices inside Kubernetes cluster with managing rest api clients with CI/CD instead of manual work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried OpenFeign? Within SpringMVC, we can use SpringMVC's `@RequestMapping` and other annotations to generate a client to the API that these annotations are pointing to. Please refer [the documentation here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html).

Now, since you want this to be automated, you may try this:

- Write an annotation processor that can process `@Controller` or whichever flavour you are using.
- This processor will generate the interface that SpringBoot needs as the Feign configuration
- The processor will generate exactly the same methods as in the controller class with the same annotations (you may need to add/remove some parameters to the SpringMVC annotations)
- This, then should be given as a Gradle `annotationProcessor` dependency

Of course, now your SpringBoot application needs `@EnableFeignClients` and the corresponding dependencies.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I haven't. I'll research and give it a try